# ASP Button requires two clicks to post back?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, file-upload, input

I'm working on a page that will allow a user to upload a photo with an HTML Input:

```
<input id="fileUpload" runat="server" type="file"   style="visibility:hidden;" />
```

I've got it `hidden` because I want to style my own upload control by using an `<img>` for the Browse button and using Jquery to trigger the fileUpload control's click event:

```
<img id="btnBrowse" alt="Choose an photo to upload..." src="images/browse.gif" />
```

JS:

```
$("#btnBrowse").click(function () {

 $('input[type=file]').click();

});
```

I'm using an  `<ASP:ImageButton>` for the Upload button and an `<ASP:TextBox>` to hold the text of the file chosen.

If I remove the `style="visibility:hidden;"`, everything works fine. But with it, when I click Upload, the file upload control's file is lost, and the page won't post back until I click Upload a second time.

I know that this is kind of a "hack" but I don't want to use an `<ASP:FileUpload>` control because it can't be customized and I didn't want to bother with a Jquery plugin if I can accomplish what I need without one.

Has anyone experienced this or have any idea how I could make this work while keeping `style="visibility:hidden;"` in place?

Many thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

It actually appears to be more related to my custom "Browse" button. I was using an `<img>` as noted, and I've tried using an `<ASP:ImageButton>` but get the same results. Anytime I click my custom Browse button (which calls JS to click the `input type=file`), after a file is chosen, my Upload button will require two clicks (And the first click wipes out the filepath of the input (like it tries to post back)?

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Just stabbing in the dark.  Have you tried "display:none"?

Comment: Have you got any form validation on the page, asp.net validator controls or otherwise?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, no luck. And there is a validator control - but it's on the master page tied to this page. Is there something I can check with that?

Comment: Try turning the validator off on the master page off temporarily to see if this is part of the problem.

Comment: I commented the validator out completely, and that didn't have any affect either.

Comment: Can you post the HTML as rendered to the page?

Comment: You don't have it in an UpdatePanel do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can attach an event to the browse image in code behind. I've done the same when adding multiple attributes to buttons, ie. an onclick point to code behind and an onchange pointed to js.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: He means. btnName.Attributes.Add();

Comment: I don't need the Browse button hooked up to the code behind. The browse button only simulates clicking the `input type=file` via Javascript. However, using my custom browse button screws something up because then my Upload button doesn't work until the 2nd Click.

Comment: also, if you have a js file already, you can use the following:

Answer (score 0):

Pure stab in the dark, try using `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden`

Answer (score 0):

also, if you have a js file already, you can use the following:

```
function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
         window.onload = func;
    }
    else {
        window.onload = function () {
            if (oldonload) {
                oldonload();
            }
            func();
        }
    }
}
addLoadEvent(whatYouWantToInit);

var whatYouWantToInit_count = 0;
function whatYouWantToInit() {
    if (whatYouWantToInit_count) { return; } // Won't let this function execute twice.
        whatYouWantToInit_count++;
        if ($('yourButton') != null) {
            $('yourButton').onclick = yourButton_click; //the function you want your onclick event to fire.
        }
}
```